# How can I parse this kind of text?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

This is the format my text is in:

```
15no16no17yes the parents who have older children always tell you the next stage is worse.18yes using only their hands and feet make some of the worst movies in the history of the world.19no
```

So the basic format is this:

`number` `yes|no` `text(may/may not be there)` repeated

The text after `yes` or `no` can be empty, or can start with a space. (I have tried to illustrate this above).

The code I have works for this format: 
`number` `yes|no` repeated

More examples of text to parse:

```
30no31yesapproximately 278 billion miles from anything.32no33no34no
30no31yesapproximately 278 billion miles from anything32no33yessince the invention of call waiting34yesGravity is a contributing factor in 73 percent of all accidents involving falling objects.
35yesanybody who owns hideous clothing36yes if you take it from another person's plate37yes172 miles per hour upside down38yesonly more intelligent39yes any product including floor wax that has fat in it
35no36yestake it from another person's plate37yes172 miles per hour upside down38no39no
35no36no37yes172 miles per hour38no39no
35no36no37yesupside down38no39no
```

How do I modify my code?

```
String regex = "^(\\d+)(yes|no)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = input.nextLine();
        String myStr = line;
        Matcher m = p.matcher(myStr);

        while(m.find()) {
            String all = m.group();
        String digits = m.group(1);
            String bool = m.group(2);
            // do stuff
            myStr = myStr.substring(all.length());
            m.reset(myStr);
        } // end while
    } // end while
```

I tried using `String regex = "^(\\d+)(yes|no)(.*)";` but the problem is that it captures everything after a `yes` or `no`.

What do I do?

PS: Please let me know if anything is unclear and I'll provide more explanations.

Comment: if the text part has no quotes/brackets etc. how can you distinguish if a text has something like "we have answered 100yes!" or you mean the text can only contain [a-zA-Z]?

Comment: Well that is part of the problem. I should have mentioned, the text can start/end with number. Would it help if you modify the text to include a tab after yes/no to distinguish between the terms?

Comment: May you post more examples of what you need to parse? A list of some examples would be good.

Comment: The problem is I don't know where is the right "yes/no"! How can I modifiy the text?

Comment: @Kent We always have a yes/no after a number. (That number is later used as index of an array). So it might be useful to say that the number, yes/no and text after that all are needed and cannot be dropped.

Comment: @user2059238: Wait a moment, I'm writing some code.

Comment: @user2059238 from your example, apart from computer program, I even cannot parse your text with my eye/brain.... what if your text part has number+yes.../no... pattern as well?

Comment: @Kent Well, it's basically like this: `number` `yes|no` `text(may/may not be there)` repeated. I'm sorry but I'm not sure how else can I clarify it.

Comment: let's say, is there a rule that your text part doesn't contain `number+yes|no` pattern? for example "303notes"

Comment: In your example, 303notes = `303` is the index (number), `no` is the yes/no part, `tes` is the text. However, if the input was 303no404yes =  `303` is the index (number), `no` is the yes/no part, `` is the text, `404` is the index (number), `yes` is the yes/no part, `` is the text

Comment: Almost there... Wait a little more...

Comment: @user2059238 you could simply answer "no, text part doesn't contain indexyes|no pattern"

Comment: I think this might be helpful: Every number before yes/no is 1 more than the previous number before yes/no, always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I think it will work.  In the end of the parsing, you will have a List of Answers. Now, you just need to make some modifications to return this List and use its answers. My algorithm just detects all the answers and where they start in the main String and with this information, slice the text. So, the algorithm have two steps (1: bounds detection, 2: string slicing). I made some comnents in my code. Hope it works.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author David Buzatto
 */
public class ASimpleParser {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new ASimpleParser().exec();
    }

    public void exec() {

        String[] in = {
            "30no31yesapproximately 278 billion miles from anything.32no33no34no",
            "30no31yesapproximately 278 billion miles from anything32no33yessince the invention of call waiting34yesGravity is a contributing factor in 73 percent of all accidents involving falling objects.",
            "35yesanybody who owns hideous clothing36yes if you take it from another person's plate37yes172 miles per hour upside down38yesonly more intelligent39yes any product including floor wax that has fat in it",
            "35no36yestake it from another person's plate37yes172 miles per hour upside down38no39no",
            "35no36no37yes172 miles per hour38no39no",
            "35no36no37yesupside down38no39no"
        };

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(\\d+)(yes|no)" );
        List<Answer> allAnswers = new ArrayList<Answer>();

        for ( String s : in ) {

            List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
            Matcher m = p.matcher( s );

            // step 1: detecting answer bounds (start)
            while ( m.find() ) {

                Answer a = new Answer();
                a.answerStart = m.group();
                a.number = m.group( 1 );
                a.yesOrNo = m.group( 2 );
                a.startAt = s.indexOf( a.answerStart );

                answers.add( a );

            }

            // step 2: slicing
            for ( int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++ ) {

                Answer a = answers.get( i );

                // needs to compare to the right one, the will have the right bounds
                if ( i != answers.size() - 1 ) {

                    Answer rightAnswer = answers.get( i + 1 );
                    a.text = s.substring( a.startAt + a.answerStart.length(), rightAnswer.startAt );

                } else { // int the last answer, the right bound is the end of the main String. s.length() may be ommited.

                    a.text = s.substring( a.startAt + a.answerStart.length(), s.length() );

                }

            }

            allAnswers.addAll( answers );

        }

        // just iterating over the answers to show them.
        for ( Answer a : allAnswers ) {
            System.out.println( a );
        }

    }

    // a private class to contain the answers data
    private class Answer {

        String answerStart;
        String number;
        String yesOrNo;
        String text;
        int startAt;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Answer{" + "number=" + number + ", answer=" + yesOrNo + ", text=" + text + ", startAt=" + startAt + '}';
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I came up with this: http://pastebin.com/VeG7reHk But I get this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -207
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
 at ASimpleParser.exec(ASimpleParser.java:67)
 at ASimpleParser.main(ASimpleParser.java:23)` when using this data set: http://pastebin.com/zgVRncbJ

I have tried to check the dataset by checking every 10 lines for each batch, and they work fine individually. The problem occurs in line 37 of input.

Comment: Sorry, line 36 of input is messing up.